# When calculating P, for diagonalization, does the order of eigenvalues matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the value of this matrix, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ to the power of $10$.

I've determined (and confirmed on Wolfram) that the eigenvalues are $5$, and $-2$. 
I started looking for P by using the eigenvalue $5$, and found the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. 
I did the same for the eigenvalue $-2$, and found eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$

I then put these together to get $P: \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -4\\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. I followed that by finding $P^{-1}: \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4\\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

The problem is, that $PAP^{-1}$ is not diagonalizing. I checked Wolfram, and I found that the reason is because my $P$ should have been $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 1\\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

My question is, what is the general rule about what eigenvalue to plug in first and how to arrange the columns of $P$?

Comment: You have and $P$ and  $P^{-1}$ swapped, should be $P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: If $\Pi$ is a permutation matrix and $\Lambda$ is diagonal, then $\Pi^{-1} \Lambda \Pi$ is also diagonal (with the same, rearranged entries). Hence if $P^{-1} A P = \Lambda$, then $(P \Pi)^{-1} A P \Pi = \Pi^{-1} \Lambda \Pi$, the rearranged diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 16):

The problem does not lie in the order of the eigenvalues or the order of the columns of $P$. What should be diagonal is $P^{-1}AP$, not $PAP^{-1}$. The order of the eigenvalues or eigenvectors do not matter, as long as the ordering of eigenvalues is consistent with the ordering of eigenvectors.

Comment: Ahaa!! Silly mistake!! Gratefulness I have to you, thank for showing me.

Comment: I made this kind of mistakes all the time.