# What is the correct phase portrait for this linear system? Does the order of eigenvalues affect the solution curves?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

I was attempting this problem in Lawrence Perko,

[image: Question]

Since the [order of eigenvalues do not matter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254909/when-calculating-p-for-diagonalization-does-the-order-of-eigenvalues-matter), I found eigenvectors such that the system is diagonalized with 4 then 2.

[image: my solution]

It is quite easy and my answer matches the one given in the solution booklet.

[image: final solution]

The problem lies in how the phase portrait is drawn.

[image: official solution]

See, in both cases, we have different transformation matrices P since the order of the eigenvectors is different. So I agree the official solution is correct and the rotation of the phase portrait makes sense given that particular P.

[image: my phase portrait]

But my phase portrait looks different now... since its not a simple rotation anymore. I transforms to P when moving from y to x. So the cross and star I marked should move to the circle and starInCircle. I am not clear what went wrong here...

Is my phase portrait wrong? Or does changing the order of eigenvectors affect the axis somehow?

Comment: Are you using his $P$?

Comment: @Moo no I'm using my P. If I use the P in the solution I get the same phase portrait. But my point is that both his and my P are the same in an important sense. It's just the order of eigenvalues that's different. The geometric representation of the trajectories of a dynamical system should be the same I feel in both cases.

Comment: If you plot the parametric curve for $(c_1e^{2t},c_2 e^{4t})$ and $(c_1e^{4t},c_2 e^{2t})$, will the phase portraits look the same?

Comment: @Moo I thought about what you said and obviously, the phase portraits won't look the same. The first case will be $y = \frac{c_2x^2}{c_1^2} $ and the second case will be $y^2 = \frac{c_2^2x}{c_1} $. I realized my mistake, I plotted the wrong phase portrait in the y space. The transformation back to the x space is just a 45 deg clockwise rotation for their P. My P has a much more complex transformation - anticlockwise 45 and then a reflection? But finally both our P bring us back to **same phase portrait** for x(t). https://i.imgur.com/vtfTMEB.png so if you write a short answer I can accept it.

Comment: Excellent work! I added a blurb as an answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent work on your part and it is great to see you questioning results.

If you do a parametric plot of $(c_1e^{2t},c_2 e^{4t})$, versus $(c_1e^{4t},c_2 e^{2t})$, they will be different.

**Hint:** are you sure you are drawing the correct phase portrait in the $y-$space?

**Hint:** The books result is correct.